# Servlets in separate WARs - partially sharing their context root

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jboss

For a web service project, I need to install two API versions of a Java EE web on my web server at

- `example.com/myservice/v1` and
- `example.com/myservice/v2`

The safest way to separate the different versions seems to be deploying them in different WAR files, one for `v1` and one for `v2`.

I created and deployed two JBoss 6 Java EE 6 Web Profile applications with these entries in jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/test/v1</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/test/v2</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Both war files deployed and ran without errors. JBoss did not complain that they use the same root context part `/test`.

**Is this a standard behaviour of a servlet container (specified) or just a JBoss feature and not guaranteed to be portable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, Oracle docs for Glassfish say that [A context root must start with a forward slash (/); and end with a string](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnaeb/index.html) - no restrictions of slash inside the context root.

Another example is JBoss docs where there is [an example of two web applications with nested context roots (paragraph 1)](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html).

Tomcat also supports nested context paths - see Naming section of [Apache Context Configuration doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

There is no requirement of not having slash inside the context root in the specification also. I think it means that as well as any other feature you may assume that it works on your application server, but the way it is configured may differ, and of course you have to test your application before moving to another container.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding context root [JBoss](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html) says:

> The context root of a web application determines which URLs Tomcat
>   will delegate to your web application. If your application's context
>   root is myapp then any request for /myapp or /myapp/* will be handled
>   by your application unless a more specific context root exists. If a
>   second web application were assigned the context root myapp/help, a
>   request for /myapp/help/help.jsp would be handled by the second web
>   application, not the first.

Two context root that you have defined in `jboss-web.xml` are i) `/test/v1` and ii) `/test/v2`. These two are entirely different since they specify two different URLs.

So your apprehension that:

> JBoss did not complain that they use the same root context part /test.

does not hold good as they are different from one another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it quotes from a link in the accepted answer by Larry0ua. I can't upvote yet but will do later. I did not expect JBoss complaining - in fact I was happy that JBoss accepts the two partially overlapping context roots.